# Grails Selenium plugin not found for name [selenium]

Tags: grails, selenium, grails-plugin

I've been trying to get the grails selenium plugin installed for the project I'm working on. I'm inside the project dir but, when I execute the following command

```
grails install-plugin selenium
```

I get the following error,

```
Resolving plugin selenium. Please wait...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    module not found: org.grails.plugins#selenium;latest.integration

==== grailsPlugins: tried

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#selenium;latest.integration!selenium.zip:

  /home/jacob/selenium/grailsSelPlugin/selTestApp/lib/selenium-[revision].zip

  /home/jacob/.grails/1.3.8/projects/selTestApp/plugins/selenium-0.1/lib/selenium-[revision].zip

==== grailsHome: tried

  /usr/share/grails/1.3.8/lib/selenium-[revision].xml

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#selenium;latest.integration!selenium.zip:

  /usr/share/grails/1.3.8/lib/selenium-[revision].zip

==== grailsHome: tried

  /usr/share/grails/1.3.8/dist/selenium-[revision].xml

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#selenium;latest.integration!selenium.zip:

  /usr/share/grails/1.3.8/dist/selenium-[revision].zip

==== grailsHome: tried

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#selenium;latest.integration!selenium.zip:

  /usr/share/grails/1.3.8/plugins/grails-selenium-[revision].zip

==== grailsCentral: tried

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#selenium;latest.integration!selenium.zip:

  http://plugins.grails.org/grails-selenium/tags/LATEST_RELEASE/grails-selenium-[revision].zip

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.grails.plugins#selenium;latest.integration: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


Error resolving plugin [name:selenium, group:org.grails.plugins,    
version:latest.integration].
Plugin not found for name [selenium] and version [not specified]
```

Any ideas? I've tried "grails clean" but aside from that I don't have many ideas and couldn't find anything about this online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once again I find myself answering my own question, but here's the answer that worked for me.

First I had to install the zip file containing the grails selenium plugin. The one I used was grails-selenium-0.8.zip (which can be found through the selenium website or a google search).

Next what was really getting me was that the GRAILS_HOME environment variable was not set correctly. I'd been using grails for months now and things such as install and clean had been working I would even get the message

```
 Grails home is set to: /usr/share/grails/1.3.8
```

however when I checked my environment variables using

```
env | grep GRAILS_HOME
```

I got nothing. So I went into .bashrc and added the following lines to the very bottom of that file,

```
export GRAILS_HOME=/usr/share/grails/1.3.8
export PATH=$GRAILS_HOME:$PATH
```

I re-started the terminal and ran

```
grails install-plugin ../grails-selenium-0.8.zip
```

and finally found success.